# While trying to import pandas library to pycharm there is an error message

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

the error message 
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Windows SDK 7.1": www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=8279

Answer (score 0):

It's telling you that you need Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 as pandas library has dependencies that refer to that version of Microsoft Visual C++. It provides you the url to download and install it. Use it, then import pandas library.